# Error: Cannot find module '/usr/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/lib/InjectorServer.js'

Tags: node.js, debugging, remote-debugging, mean-stack, node-inspector

I work on a mean.js application (on top of express.js > node.js).
I succeed to debug it locally (on kubuntu) with node inspector, no problem.
But I fail to debug it remotely (from an ubuntu server) , after I pushed my app on the network.

I get this error on the devtools console:

> Page.getResourceContent failed. Error: ENOENT, open
>   '/home/remi/publisher-server/server.js' Error: Cannot find module
>   '/usr/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/lib/InjectorServer.js'

But the `server.js`'s file permissions are `775`, and are owned by me.

If you look at this screenshot you can see that the browser access to all files tree and contents:

[image]

However, if you look at that one, you'll see that only the `server.js` seems unreadable (content tab is empty):

[image]

Here are the steps I follow:

I login my server with this ssh options to redirect the`5858` port

```
ssh -L 5858:localhost:5858 my-remote-host
```

From the ssh session I run the app with `--debug` option:

```
$ cd ~/publisher-server
$ node --debug server.js 
debugger listening on port 5858
Application loaded using the "development" environment configuration
MEAN.JS application started on port 3000
```

From my laptop I run :

```
$ node-inspector
Node Inspector v0.10.1
Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?ws=127.0.0.1:8080&port=5858 to start debugging.
Cannot resolve real path of /home/remi/publisher-server/server.js: Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/remi/publisher-server'
```

You can notice the last line that throw the error that I found again in the devtools console when I finally browse `http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?ws=127.0.0.1:8080&port=5858` :

> Page.getResourceContent failed. Error: ENOENT, open
>   '/home/remi/publisher-server/server.js' Error: Cannot find module
>   '/usr/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/lib/InjectorServer.js'

This makes me a bit crazy, what I'm making wrong ?

Comment: I have the same exact problem...
node-inspector 0.10.2 and node 0.10.33

Comment: I had the same problem, it seems that the requested path should be on the node running server not on node-inspector server. I think it's not designed for working in different machine due to needs for accessing files in different relative directories.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem but using docker.. Did you get a solution to this? (weird thing is that I was able to do remote debug with node-debug at a certain point of time then it broke :( )